# Getting jniLibs to work with Gradle 2.10

Tags: android, gradle, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use a native library but I'm getting this error and I can't figure out how to solve it. I'm with this for more than a day by now. Checked a lot of questions and nothing worked. The error is always the same when calling `System.loadLibrary("createdata")`:

> UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load createdata from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

**Attempt 1:** Just keep the file in the default folder - *src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libcreatedata.so*

**Attempt 2:** Move the file to another folder - *src/main/libs/armeabi/libcreatedata.so* -  and added this to the module's build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs/'
    }
}
```

---

### NOTES

- I called **libcreatedata.so** to the lib's file
- The file is within the folders **armeabi**, **armeabi-v7a** and **arm64-v8a**
- I checked the generated .apk, and it contains the file in **lib/armeabi** *(and others)*
- Android Studio 2.1.1
- Gradle:

  ```
  com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
  ```

---

### UPDATE

As per request, here are the apk's folding:

- **Root**
  [image]
- **lib**
  [image]
- **armeabi**
  [image]